# Add properties to term object

Tags: categories, terms

A typical `WP_Term` Object, for category might look like this;

```
WP_Term Object
(
  [term_id] => 5
  [name] => News and Views
  [slug] => news-and-views
  [term_group] => 0
  [term_taxonomy_id] => 5
  [taxonomy] => category
  [description] => 
  [parent] => 0
  [count] => 22
  [filter] => raw
  [term_order] => 1
  [cat_ID] => 5
  [category_count] => 22
  [category_description] => 
  [cat_name] => News and Views
  [category_nicename] => news-and-views
  [category_parent] => 0
)
```

It would be very desirable to have a singular name. Is there a way to extend the WP_Term class with a hook to add `singular_name` property?

I realise that it is possible with ACF but this is not really meta data